# How can I access and update a List from MonoBehaviour script in Editor script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The MonoBehaviour script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickupObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public List<GameObject> pickUpObjects = new List<GameObject>();
}
```

And the editor script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(PickupObjects))]
public class PickupObjectsEditor : Editor
{
    [MenuItem("GameObject/Generate as Pickup Item", false, 30)]
    public static void GeneratePickupItems()
    {
        if (Selection.gameObjects.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Selection.gameObjects.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Selection.gameObjects[i].GetComponent<TestScript>() == null)
                {
                    Selection.gameObjects[i].AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
                    Selection.gameObjects[i].AddComponent<TestScript>();
                }

                Selection.gameObjects[i].layer = 9;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want in the editor script after the loop to add the objects to the list in the MonoBehaviour so I can see the objects that are now picked up items in the list in the MonoBehaviour script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `Editor` redundant. At least if it does nothing else. It is not required for createing a `MenuItem` method.

You can't directly do this since you would somehow need to have a reference to your `MonoBehaviour` instance.

One option could be to find it in the scene using [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html)

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

public class PickupObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public List<GameObject> pickUpObjects = new List<GameObject>();

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    // This disabled the menu item as long as there is no instance of PickupObjects in the scene.
    [MenuItem("GameObject/Generate as Pickup Item", true, 30)]
    private static bool CanGeneratePickupItems()
    {
        return FindObjectOfType<PickupObjects>();
    }

    [MenuItem("GameObject/Generate as Pickup Item", false, 30)]
    private static void GeneratePickupItems()
    {
        var instance = FindObjectOfType<PicupObjects>();

        if(!instance) return;

        // Clear the list first? Otherwise selection will be added to already existing entries
        // (Duplicates are filtered out later below anyway)
        instance.pickupObjects.Clear();

        if (Selection.gameObjects.Length <= 0) return;

        foreach (var selectedObj in Selection.gameObjects)
        {
            if (selectedObj.GetComponent<TestScript>() == null)
            {       
                selectedObj.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
                selectedObj.AddComponent<TestScript>();               
            }

            selectedObj.layer = 9;

            if(!instance.pickupObjects.Contains(selectedObj)) instance.pickupObjects.Add(selectedObj);
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*